# Is there any xarray code for selecting data in the shape of a parallelogram?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, multidimensional-array, reshape, python-xarray

I have a temperature data with dimensions YC and XC.   I'm interested in selecting data within the red parallelogram shape depicted in the figure. [xarray.DataArray'YC: 720 XC: 560](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEjNf.png).

However, when using the 'sel' function in xarray,`T2=T1.sel(YC=slice(4,16),XC=slice(70,76))` it retrieves a straight rectangular shape that doesn't meet the intended selection.